# Задачи по C#

Tags: c#

Дайте кто - нибудь пару задач по C#, решил изучить, а практиковаться негде.

Comment: Напишите любую игру из тетриса, или змейку, или сапёра, что-то подобное. Это интереснее, чем какие-то абстрактные задачи.

Comment: Напиши программу, решающую задачу Эйнштейна (Кто хозяин рыбки).  
Не слабо прокачаешь работу с массивами и построение алгоритмов в целом :)

Comment: Игра - не вариант, а за задачу Эйнштейна - спасибо, попробую...

Comment: Задачи по обработке массивов. Там много интересного... А также задачи по работе с классами: создание, наследование, полиморфизм, инкапсуляция... Вообщем горизонт фантазии неограничен)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрите книгу Никиты Культина "C# в задачах и примерах"

Comment: Спасибо!, обязательно скачаю на читалку.

Answer (score 3):

[Сборник](http://www.braingames.ru/?path=category&catname=prog&displayOpts=all) отличных задач для программиста.

Comment: Простоваты задачки, но всёравно спасибо

Comment: Мне про цикл for понравилась- не сразу приходишь к осознанию третьего варианта :)

Comment: я помню этой задачей про циклы всему факультету мозг вынес=)

Comment: @Spectre, я удалю Ваш коммент с ответом на задачу, потому что не интересно так, сайт рассчитан, что люди сами будут решать, а не копировать и вставлять.

Comment: >Как поменять местами значения двух числовых переменных без использования дополнительных переменных и/или памяти? В используемом языке нет оператора обмена значениями (вроде XCHG ассемблера).

    a+=b;
    b=a-b;
    a-=b;

Comment: @Spectre, неверно :)  

    byte a, b;
    a=255;
    b=255

Comment: именно поэтому тип a и b я не указал=)

Comment: Когда я примерно такой ответ отправил на проверку модератор мне ответил, что ответ неверен и:  

    Ваше решение должно работать для большинства языков программирования (в том числе для тех, в которых на целочисленные значения выделяют фиксированное число байтов). А в них возможно возникновение Exception при переполнении при определённых настройках компилятора (например, Visual C или Delphi).

Comment: @ReinRaus: (запоздалый комментарий) тогда покатит решение с XOR вместо +/-.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите этот сайт: [олимпиадные задачи по программированию](http://school-collection.edu.ru/catalog/rubr/7d5f9dcd-3c0e-c52c-0181-ed064bbfa22d/86787/).

Comment: А где тут C#, это сайт для школьного уровня, т. е. там кроме паскаля ничего нету...

Comment: Если задача решается с применением паскаля, это не значит что их нельзя решить с применением C#.

Comment: Задачи школьного уровня, типа того, что найдите количество цифр в числе, и т. д.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть дано число N. Известно, что его можно разбить на сумму трех, не равных нулю чисел. Напишите программу, которая выведет на экран все такие разложения. Например, число 6 можно получить двумя способами: 1+2+3, 2+2+2.